# Prove that $x$ is congruent to $y \pmod m$ if and only if $x = km + y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Prove that $x$ is congruent to $y \pmod m$ if and only if $x = km + y$

I'm not sure how to prove this, and honestly I don't really understand why it's true in the first place.

Comment: That is pretty much the definition of congruence.

Comment: I mean I guess I understand how it's true, but what would the proof look like?

Comment: @GoldPonyBoy that depends on what your textbook (or notes) use as the definition as "$x$ is congruent to $y$ (mod $m$)"

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If $x \equiv y \pmod m$, then after division of $x$ by $m$, I have a remainder of $y$, assuming $0 \leq y < m$. So, via the division algorithm, $x = mq +y$. 
The other direction is trivial using the division algorithm.

Comment: No, $10\equiv 13\pmod 3$, but after division of $10$ by $3$ one does **not** have a remainder of $13$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown there is a difference in notation. $\equiv$ implies that the $y$ is indeed between $0$ and $m$, where an $=$ does not imply this. Your above statement should be $10 = 13 \pmod m$. The statement of the question implies that $0 \leq y <m$.

Comment: No, $10\equiv 13\pmod 3$ is the accepted notation. The question does not state that, nor imply that, $0\le y<m$. Please consult elementary texts on number theorry.